# Why doesn’t the bool value set inside a for loop?

Tags: python

I want my code to print a phrase if it's the first value and to just print out the value for every subsequent value.
Therefore I'm trying to set a flag to do so, but it's not working and just prints out the phrase with every value. Why does the bool value not get set and therefore direct subsequent iterations to use the else statement?

Python code:

```
hi = [{"item1": "one"}, {"item2": "two"}]
for stype in hi:
        keys = list(stype.keys())
        first = True
        for typ in keys:
                if first:
                        print("Value! ", stype.get(typ))
                        first = False
                else:
                        print("\t", stype.get(typ))
```

Comment: Is that really your indentation?

Comment: The indentation is wrong, the quotes aren't normal, valid quotes... Please post your exact, real code.

Comment: Move `first = True` to before the `for` loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you! Can you explain to me why it doesn't work in the current state? Why is that when first is set to False in the second for loop but doesn't maintain that value?

Comment: Put two entries in one of the dictionaries and you will see that your approach works for each dictionary. But after each dictionary you reset `first` to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You reset the value for `first` for every entry in the list. Set `first = True` before you start the outer loop and nowhere else.

I fixed some other overcomplicated things in the code. There is no need to loop over the keys if all you want are the values.

```
hi = [{"item1": "one", 'item1.1': 'kind of one'}, {"item2": "two"}]
first = True
for stype in hi:
    for value in stype.values():
        if first:
            print(f"Value! {value}")
            first = False
        else:
            print(f"\t{value}")
```

Result

```
Value! one
    kind of one
    two
```

Answer (score 0):

First always reset to True in outer loop.

Alternatively, you can also check if the key is in first index of the list instead:

```
hi = [{"item1": "one"}, {"item2": "two"}, {'item3': 'three'}]

for stype in hi:
    for typ in stype:
        print("Value! ", stype[typ]) if typ in hi[0] else print("\t", stype[typ])

# Value!  one
#    two
#    three
```

Comment: Or `print(f"{(chr(9), 'Value! ')[typ in hi[0]]}{stype[typ]}")`. But I don't like the access with the key and the search in the list. If performance is not a problem then it's fine.

Comment: @Matthias Wow... I love that tuple indices as alternate `if` to check 0 or 1. 
Yeah, make sense. I agree